# 別々のVagrantfileで定義して運用していたマシンをmulti-machine構成に集約したい

Tags: vagrant

現在、以下の3つのマシンを立てて使っています。

```sh
$ find . -maxdepth 4
.
./master
./master/.vagrant
./master/.vagrant/machines
./master/.vagrant/machines/default
./master/Vagrantfile
./slave
./slave/.vagrant
./slave/.vagrant/machines
./slave/.vagrant/machines/default
./slave/Vagrantfile
./staging
./staging/.vagrant
./staging/.vagrant/machines
./staging/.vagrant/machines/default
./staging/Vagrantfile
```

これを以下のようにmulti-machine構成の単一のVagrantfileで定義するようにしたいと考えています。

```ruby
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.define "master" do |master|
  end

  config.vm.define "slave" do |slave|
  end

  config.vm.define "staging" do |staging|
  end
end
```

見たところ、以下の作業で何事もなかったようにvagrant upできそうですが、これで必要十分でしょうか。

1. {machine}/.vagrant/machines/default ディレクトリを ./vagrant/machines/{machine} に移動する

```sh
    ./.vagrant/machines/master  # ./master/.vagrant/machines/default
    ./.vagrant/machines/slave   # ./slave/.vagrant/machines/default
    ./.vagrant/machines/staging # ./staging/.vagrant/machines/default
```

2. path/to/machine/virtualbox/synced_folders ファイルにある絶対パスを書き換える

```js
    {"virtualbox":
      {"/vagrant":
        {"guestpath":"/vagrant",
         "hostpath":"/path/to/root",
         "disabled":false}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

結局、1.のディレクトリ移動だけで済みました。(Vagrantfileの`synced_folder`で設定しているパスの調整はしましたが。) `virtualbox/synced_folders` ファイルは起動時にVagrantが自動生成するので、ノータッチでよいようです。

1. `vagrant halt`
2. ディレクトリ移動
3. Vagrantfileをマージ
4. `vagrant up`

Comment: 既存の単一マシン Vagrant ファイルに、サブのマシンを追加したい場合も、これでいける(よろしくやってくれる)ことを確認しました。